# rake aborted! LoadError:libicudata.so.63: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, circleci

With the upgrade from ruby2.7.2 -> 2.7.6, the CircleCI run environment is now also using the next generation image.
Then I got an error in the run command of Database setup" step. We are at a loss as to how to investigate and solve the problem, so we have decided to post this.

circleci/config

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
#   - image: circleci/ruby:2.7.2-node-browsers <- この部分を修正
   - image: cimg/ruby:2.7.6-browsers  
      environment:
        PGHOST: localhost
        PGUSER: postgres
        RAILS_ENV: test
        TZ: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo
        PARALLEL_TESTS_CONCURRENCY: 2
    - image: redis:3.2.11
    - image: postgres:10.4
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
        POSTGRES_DB: db_test
        BUNDLER_VERSION: 2.3.11
    parallelism: 2

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-
          - bootsnap-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Revision }}
          - bootsnap-cache-{{ .Branch }}
          - bootsnap-cache

      - run:
          name: setup bundler
          command: |
            gem update --system
            gem install bundler -v 2.3.11

      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            bundle install --jobs=4 --retry=3 --path vendor/bundle

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ./vendor/bundle
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      - save_cache:
          key: bootsnap-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Revision }}
          paths:
            - tmp/cache/bootsnap-load-path-cache
            - tmp/cache/bootsnap-compile-cache
      - save_cache:
          key: bootsnap-cache-{{ .Branch }}
          paths:
            - tmp/cache/bootsnap-load-path-cache
            - tmp/cache/bootsnap-compile-cache
      - save_cache:
          key: bootsnap-cache
          paths:
            - tmp/cache/bootsnap-load-path-cache
            - tmp/cache/bootsnap-compile-cache

      # Database setup
      - run:
          name: Database setup
          command: |
            bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
            bundle exec rake parallel:create[$PARALLEL_TESTS_CONCURRENCY]
            bundle exec rake parallel:migrate[$PARALLEL_TESTS_CONCURRENCY]

      # run tests!
      - run:
          name: Run rspec in parallel
          command: |
            mkdir /tmp/test-results
            bundle exec parallel_rspec -n $PARALLEL_TESTS_CONCURRENCY $(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)

      # collect reports
      - store_test_results:
          path: /tmp/test-results
      - store_artifacts:
          path: /tmp/test-results
          destination: test-results
```

output error

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake parallel:create[$PARALLEL_TESTS_CONCURRENCY]
bundle exec rake parallel:migrate[$PARALLEL_TESTS_CONCURRENCY]

rake aborted!
LoadError: libicudata.so.63: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/lib/charlock_holmes.rb:1:in `<main>'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler.rb:176:in `require'
/home/circleci/repo/config/application.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/circleci/repo/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/circleci/repo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli.rb:483:in `exec'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.11/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the `charlock_holmes` gem. It is linked against a version of `libicudata` which is not present on your system any more. I suggest to uninstall the gem and reinstall. This will recompile it and hopefully it will pick up the correct `libicudata` version.

If you are not in control of the system where the gem is installed, you will need to file a bug report. In that case it looks like a misconfigured remote system. In either case `charlock_holmes` should be recompiled and make sure `libicudata` is present on the system.